# Prolog cut "!" operator in erlang

Tags: prolog, erlang

I have enough solid prolog background and now I am going to develop a code in erlang. Those languages looks enough similar, except the cut "!" operator, which is very useful in prolog. 
Now I am wondering if there is such operator in erlang? Or may be I am missing something and there is no need in such operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for this operator; in Prolog it's used to limit backtracking, but in Erlang there's no backtracking in that sense.

The syntax of Erlang is very similar to Prolog, because it was originally developed in Prolog and could trivially be parsed using its standard library, but semantics not so much.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please describe the "Erlang there's no backtracking in that sense" in more details?

Comment: I mean as the erlang is recursive there should be backtracking, or I am missing something here?

Comment: @user2420079 I am not sure what's there to explain. Prolog is a logical language with backtracking (e.g. http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/backtrack.html); Erlang is a functional language and doesn't have backtracking. It doesn't search for solutions like Prolog does, doesn't have an equivalent to predicates succeeding multiple times, etc.

Comment: Would the "member" function from the reference in erlang work differently? I mean will "member(X, [a, a, a])." show only one result?

Comment: OK. Now I understand! It will not even try to find an X. Many thanks.

Comment: If you tried to use `member(X, [a, a, a])` in Erlang like in Prolog, you'd get "error: unbound variable X" (not exact wording).

Comment: Of interest: [A History of the Erlang VM](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/389/EFSF11-ErlangVM.pdf)